# bash script - zenity list with if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, zenity

I want a little help with my script.
I want to run some commands inside zenity list.
here is my code

```
check=$(cat file.txt | grep -c "word")
opt1=$(coomand..)
opt2=$(command..)
opt3=$(command..)

respo=$(zenity  --list  --checklist  --column "Choose" --column "" FALSE "$opt1" FALSE "$opt2" FALSE "$opt3"   --separator=":")
(
[[ $respo = $opt1 ]] && command
[[ $respo = $opt2 ]] && command
[[ $respo = $opt3 ]] && command

if [ $check = "0" ] ; then
:
else
command 1
command 2
command 3
command 4
command 5
command 6
fi
)
```

My problem is that doesn't work **if else** statement.
That i want is if **$check** result is 0 then continue without running any command. If result is 1 or bigger then runnig some commands.
Any help accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
check=$(cat file.txt | grep -c "word")
if [ $check = "0" ] ; then
```

You can just do:

```
if ! grep -q "word" file.txt; then
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. I’ve re-read the question and I’ve agreed (+1). How do you response so quickly? I’ve deleted my comment just 30 seconds after posted it.

Comment: Thanks. I saw your message in alerts so responded but later deleted it when I saw your comment disappearing.